# Nodejs in vercel - Dynamically create folder in vercel

Tags: node.js, vercel, node.js-fs

Im using vercel to deploy my project's backend part - nodejs with express

I have to create folder in server dynamically and its working fine in localhost but not working vercel after deploy

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');
fse.mkdirsSync(path.join(process.cwd(),`/tmp/${folderName}`));
```

**error message is - error: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/var/task/tmp/645b946dc74ce56d5d55f32d'"**

Any solution for it ?